# No API definition provided - Swagger through Flask/python not loading the API/Swagger UI

Tags: python, nginx, flask, swagger

I created a basic Flask application with some built-in RESTFUL API capabilities. I basically followed this guide: [Flask-Api-Guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/structuring-a-flask-restplus-web-service-for-production-builds-c2ec676de563/?source=post_page-----7e96f2da8850----------------------). I managed to place the application in a docker container - some struggling was involved, refer to my other questions - [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11897430/kevayacht). I am now running Nginx as my "webserver"/"reverse proxy server"  with Gunicorn, Flask and Python 3 in docker containers.

Everything starts up successfully, but when navigating to the relevant web page I get this message (below), instead of the expected swagger UI.

```
No API definition provided.
```

I have read posts suggesting this could be due to Nginx, and https. I would like to know how to configure Nginx and/or my Flask application to be able to view the Swagger UI.

Basically I need help on the best practice or "proper" method of prod deployment for a Swagger UI for this API server. If anyone could be of assistance in this regard it would be awesome.

I have attempted modifications to the Nginx conf file in hopes of finding a quick fix to the issue without any success.